# Unix vs Excel sort

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, unix, sorting, filenames

I have the following list of files sorted according to Excel:

```
a1.txt
a10.txt
a11.txt
a12.txt
a2.txt
```

If I use `sort` on Unix/Linux, I get the following order:

```
a10.txt
a11.txt
a12.txt
a1.txt
a2.txt
```

where you can see a different behavior for the character `.`. Is there an option to get the same order as Excel? I tried -b, -g, -n, ... without success.

Comment: Hm, I would think -n would work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
env LC_ALL=C sort
```

From the `man` page of `sort`:

```
  *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the  environment  affects  sort
   order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
   byte values.
```

[See this StackOverflow question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881/why-doesnt-sort-sort-the-same-on-every-machine)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried it before on a csh shell by typing `set LC_ALL=C` but it did not work. After changing it to `setenv LC_ALL C`, it now works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @tristof - I found that this did not work with `bash` on Ubuntu, but `sort -V` did the job. I am indebted to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856030/linux-command-sort-according-to-fields-numerical-value/34054179#34054179).

Comment: Running bash version 4.3.11(1) on Linux Mint here, and `env LC_ALL=C sort newfile.txt` gives the desired sort order of
`a1.txt`
`a10.txt`
`a11.txt`
`a12.txt`
`a2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following command : `sort -d` ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had tried the dictionary order `-d` and it does not work. Thanks anyway!